# "returns a reference to data owned by the current function" error in String to &str conversion

Tags: rust

Trying to solve [the exercise](https://exercism.org/tracks/rust/exercises/anagram) in Exercism.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&'a str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    let word_lowercase = word.to_lowercase();
    let stream = possible_anagrams.into_iter()
        .map(|c| c.to_lowercase())
        .filter(|c| word_lowercase != *c)
        .collect::<HashSet<String>>();
    let cmp_word = sorted_word(word_lowercase.as_str());
    stream.into_iter()
        .filter(|c| cmp_word == sorted_word(c))
        .map(|s| {
            s.as_str()  // line with the error
        })
        .collect::<HashSet<&str>>()
}

fn sorted_word(word: &str) -> String {
    let mut word_chars = word.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    word_chars.sort_unstable();
    word_chars.iter().collect::<String>()
}
```

But this code doesn't compile because of the error:

```
Compiling anagram v0.0.0 (/mnt/exercism-iteration)
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to function parameter `s`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:13
   |
13 |             s.as_str()
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

Tried several ways how to fix it, but with no success. How can it be solved?

Comment: Hint: you allocate a `String`, which is an owned string, from which you derive a `&str`, which holds a reference to the `String`, which is dropped at the end of the function. So you want to return a dangling reference, which the compiler prevents. You will need to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointer for @sarema.

Implemented as (might be more efficient, please answer if you know how :)):

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

pub fn anagrams_for<'a>(word: &str, possible_anagrams: &[&'a str]) -> HashSet<&'a str> {
    let word_lowercase = word.to_lowercase();
    let stream = possible_anagrams.into_iter()
        .filter(|c| word_lowercase != c.to_lowercase());
    let cmp_word = sorted_word(word_lowercase.as_str());
    stream.into_iter()
        .filter(|c| cmp_word == sorted_word(&c.to_lowercase()).as_str())
        .map(|c| *c)
        .collect::<HashSet<&str>>()
}

fn sorted_word(word: &str) -> String {
    let mut word_chars = word.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    word_chars.sort_unstable();
    word_chars.iter().collect::<String>()
}
```

Comment: interesting problem! I came up with the same solution overall, mine is just less verbose, instead of doing `string.as_str()` just do `&string`, String Deref to &str. Also, you don't need to convert the sorted vec of char to a string. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c541727860046c18fc5a64a54f9e6586)